# How did "normal" come to mean "perpendicular"?

Tags: ho.history-overview, terminology

How and when did the word "normal" acquire [this meaning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_(geometry))? When I first thought of this, I couldn't really come up with any explanation that wasn't complete speculation -- pretty much all I was able to see was that it isn't any stranger than "right" in "right angle" -- the angle is probably as right as the lines are normal. But on reading the etymology note in the entry for "normal" in the American Heritage Dictionary,

> *Middle English, from Late Latin normalis, from Latin, made according to the square, from norma, carpenter's square;*

I thought that was probably it -- it probably came from the perpendicular sides of a carpenter's square. Did it then? And how was it introduced? If this is indeed what's going on, either the meaning must have been introduced long ago, when people still realized what the etymology of "normal" is, or some really erudite mathematician must have introduced it, perhaps to show off their erudition.

So how did it happen?

Comment: There are way too many things in mathematics called "normal," "regular," etc.

Comment: @MonroeEskew Indeed, there are. :) I asked this question because a of a similar complaint I read on this site today.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328662/etymology-of-the-word-normal-perpendicular --- *normalis* already meant *right-angled* in classical Latin.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thank you. This answers my question completely. I'm not sure what the procedure is now. Perhaps you could make it an answer, and I'll accept it?

Comment: So now we should ask the converse question: if *normal* originally meant *right-angled*, how did it come to mean *ordinary*? (Although that is probably a question for another place than MO...)

Comment: Can I suggest this to be moved to Linguistics.SE?

Comment: @KetilTveiten: Both meanings were present when the word entered the English language. Latin _normalis_ referred literally to a builder's square but carried the secondary meaning of 'things conforming to the usual rules' which eventually gave way to the modern meaning of 'normal'.

Comment: @Anixx Linguistics would have been a good place at the outset, but now that Carlo Beenakker has taken the trouble to give a scholarly reply and has been rewarded here for it, it wouldn't be right IMO to transfer it. Also I think the mathematicians here will learn something they probably wouldn't have learned otherwise.

Comment: You might also look up "regular" and "rule", which both come ultimately from Latin "regula", original meaning a straight piece of wood.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

*normalis* already meant *right-angled* in classical Latin; for example, *angulus normalis* appears in the first century text *De institutione oratoria* (volume XI, paragraph 3.141) by [Marcus Fabius Quintilianus.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintilian)

In a [commentary](http://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/009268024) on this text from the fifteenth century this early use of the word "normalis" is explained as "rectus", see screenshot:

[image]

"Angulus normalis est idem qui angulus rectus" = "a normal angle is the same as a right angle"

---

In response to Ketil Tveiten's question: "How did normal come to mean ordinary" : according to this [source,](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=normal) the meaning of *normal* as *conforming to common standards* seems to be of recent origin (1828?).

Comment: Math unrelated: Does rectum [end of intestines] does anything to do with being right?

Comment: @jnovacho --- "rectum" : shortened from New Latin "rectum intestinum"  the straight intestine

Comment: @jnovacho yes, the both are from PIE root o̯reĝ- (***o̯reĝtos*** = right, correct, ***o̯reĝti*** = guides, directs, ***o̯reĝs*** = king, ***o̯reĝi̯om*** = kingdom etc)

Comment: @Anixx: I’m struggling to reconcile your notation with common notation in PIE phonology. When you write “o̯”, do you mean “u̯”, one of the laryngeals, or something else? When you write “ĝ”, do you mean “ǵ”, “gʷ”, or either of these aspirated?

Comment: @Emil Jeřábek o̯ is the laryngeal, ĝ is "palatal" or something(nobody knows what it was in reality). The later notation is common (e.g. as in Mallory & Adams, Fortson etc), so what are you referring to as "common notation"?

Comment: @Anixx: Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps it should be mentioned that while *normalis* did mean perpendicular in classical Latin, it was not the only possible (and perhaps not the preferred) choice of words.

I asked about [expressing perpendicularity in classical Latin](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/459/79) at the new [Latin Language SE site](https://latin.stackexchange.com/).
The answer given there lists a number of expressions, mainly from [Vitruvius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitruvius):

- *πρὸς ὀρθᾶς* — yes, this Greek expression was used in Latin.
- *ad normam* — according to *norma*, a square employed by carpenters, masons, etc., for making right angles.
- *ad perpendiculum* — according to *perpendiculum*, a [plumb-line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plumb_bob)
- *ad perpendiculum et normam* — combination of the previous two
- *directus* — "straight", essentially the same as *rectus* used in the medieval commentary Carlo mentions

There is a finite amount of extant Latin literature and perpendicularity is not the most common of subjects, so it is difficult to tell what exactly are the differences between these phrases in usage or frequency.
The examples listed above, apart from *directus*, mean "orthogonally".
For the adjective "orthogonal" one might use *directus*, *rectus* or indeed *normalis*.
Vitruvius does not use the word *normalis* at all.

Notice that *norma* and *perpendiculum* are two different tools used to create straight angles, not geometrical descriptions of the angle itself.

I am not aware of any ancient mathematical texts in Latin, either original or translations.
It would be interesting to see which expression would be chosen in mathematical context.
If you know any suitable sources, consider answering ["Where to find ancient mathematics in Latin?"](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/400/79).

(The phrase mentioned in Carlo's answer can be found in the [Perseus service](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2007.01.0068%3Abook%3D11%3Achapter%3D3%3Asection%3D141) together with an [English translation](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2007.01.0069%3Abook%3D11%3Achapter%3D6%3Asection%3D141) in a more readable and searchable form.)

Answer (score 2):

I addition to what has been said I would also like to point out that Geometry began as a tool for construction. When building, almost all corners are right angles. In other words a 'standard' corner is a right angle. When you think of it in these terms the common usage of the word normal is a metaphor. For example, "I normally get chocolate ice cream" could be phrased "I build walls at right angles with about the same frequency as I choose chocolate ice cream".

Comment: Do you have any basis for this suggestion for the etymology, or is it simply "you guess it might be so"?

Comment: AFAIK, it is a myth. I originally heard the story from a high school math teacher who prefaced it by saying that the actual meaning was lost to time and this was just one possibility. I don't think it matters though because this is the best way I know of to understand the relation which is what really matters IMHO.